# Capturing KeyDown events in separate functions

Tags: delphi

If I have procedure that responses to `WM_KEYDOWN` event, then the Form's `OnKeyDown` events does not work. The params (`wParam` and `lParam` for `WM_KEYDOWN`, and `Key` and `Shift` for `OnKeyDown` are different).

If I have an `Action` that captures some key, then neither the `WM_KEYDOWN` event nor the `OnKeyDown` events works (for that key).

`KeyDown` and `KeyUp` can capture events of press and release key, but can't capture events of repeat key (non-ASCII), but I need to capture repeat events for keys (non-ASCII) as well as press and release events.

```
 TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Action1: TAction;
    procedure Action1Execute(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
      Shift: TShiftState);
  private
    procedure WMKeyDown(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_KEYDOWN;
  end;
  
procedure TForm1.WMKeyDown(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
// nothing special
end;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
// this event does not work if WM_KEYDOWN event is present
end;

procedure TForm1.Action1Execute(Sender: TObject);
begin
// both events above do not work for key specified in Action1.ShortCut
end;
```

Comment: "*If I have procedure that responses to WM_KEYDOWN event, then the Form's "OnKeyDown" events does not work*" - are you blocking the message from reaching the default handler? Please show your actual code. "*`wParam` and `lParam` for `WM_KEYDOWN`, and `Key` and `Shift` for `OnKeyDown` are different*" - in what way exactly? Please be more specific.

Comment: Some interesting reading for you : [A Key's Odyssey](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38447): "*This article follows the path of a keystroke message through the VCL. You will learn how the key processing is implemented, how the OnKey events work and what intervention points for the programmer can be found in the whole process.*"

Comment: Just wanted to translate `wParam` and `lParam` to `Key` and `Shift` and then manually call `OnKeyDown`. Actually right now I don't use them both at the same time, but just wanted to know.

Comment: Read and try to understand what **inherited** does in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declaring_a_New_Message-handling_Method).

Comment: @jsmith "*just wanted to translate `wParam` and `lParam` to `Key` and `Shift`*" - the `wParam` is the character `Key` code, just use it as-is. As for `Shift`, the VCL uses the [`KeyDataToShiftState()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.KeyDataToShiftState) function to convert the `lParam` into a `TShiftState`. But that does not include the repeat count. For that, you would need to extract those bits from the `lParam` directly.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to capture WM_KEYDOWN event not only on form, but on all child controls (focused) without having custom class for each? When any of the component is focused, form doesn't receive WM_KEYDOWN event. I need this event to handle press/release/repeat, what OnKeyDown event does not provide.